# what should be the HTTP request method for soft delete (not deleting but marking attribute as deleted: true in DB)

Tags: http

Typescript API

what should be the HTTP request method for soft delete (not deleting but marking  attribute as deleted: true in DB)

Answer (score 3):

HTTP doesn't have a soft-delete concept, so there's 2 options here:

If you (soft-)delete the resource, can you still access the resource via the API or do you get a 404/410 error?

If you *can* still access the resource via the API, then from the perspective of HTTP you didn't delete the resource. It's just a flag/property on a resource, so you can use the 'normal' way to update the resource (PUT/PATCH).

If the resource emits a 404 or 410 error after deleting, it means from the perspective of HTTP the resource really got deleted. It doesn't matter if you soft-deleted it in the database, it's irrelevant for HTTP. In this case you should use the `DELETE` method to remove the item.